# Titanium display the datas from the table in tableview

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium..I have created a tableview and I want to display the data from the database in the labels which are created and in the tableview form and could not achieve it..

**Code:**

```
var triplistview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    width : Titanium.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout : 'horizontal',
    padding : '10dp',
    separatorColor : theme_background
    // margin:'10dp',
});
scrollView.add(triplistview);
var data = [];

    var db = Titanium.Database.open('trip');

    db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newtrip (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, triplabel TEXT,tripname TEXT,destination TEXT,fromdate TEXT,todate TEXT)');
    while (resultrows.isValidRow()) {

            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            rightImage : '/images/right1.png',

            layout : 'absolute',
            //title :  '' + 'Destination' + '' + '' + resultrows.fieldByName('destination') + '' + 'From Date:' + '' + '' + resultrows.fieldByName('fromdate') + '' + 'To Date:' + '' + resultrows.fieldByName('todate')
        });

        row.add(tripnamelabel);
        row.add(buttonedit);
        row.add(buttondelete);
        row.add(fromdate);
        row.add(dash);
        row.add(todate);
        triplistview.add(row);
    row.className = 'control';
        data.push(row);

        resultrows.next();
    }
    triplistview.setData(data);
    resultrows.close();
    db.close();
```

These are the label I have created

```
 var tripnamelabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:resultrows.fieldByName('destination'),
    color : theme_style,
    font : {
        fontSize : '15dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    top : '10dp',
    left : '10dp',
});
 var buttonedit = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage : '/images/list_edit.png',
    top : '20dp',
    width : wb,
    height : hb,
    right : '20dp'
});
var buttondelete = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage : '/images/delete_ic.png',
    top : '20dp',
    width : wb,
    height : hb,
    right : '60dp'
});

var fromdate = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:resultrows.fieldByName('fromdate') 
    color : 'Black',
    font : {
        fontSize : '13dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    top : '40dp',
    left : '10dp',
    right : '10dp',
    bottom : '20dp'
});

var dash = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : '-',
    color : 'Black',
    font : {
        fontSize : '15dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    top : '40dp',
    left : '80dp',
    right : '10dp',
    bottom : '20dp'
});

var todate = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:resultrows.fieldByName('todate') 
    color : 'Black',
    font : {
        fontSize : '13dp',
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    top : '40dp',
    left : '90dp',
    right : '10dp',
    bottom : '20dp'
});
```

Please help me in this as I am stuck in this for more than a day and I am getting this error

**[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1**

Comment: i think the error you mentioned is installation of apk realted and not code

Comment: it was saying failed in parsing code in myfilename.js..

Comment: could you mention names of files above the code

Comment: these are in the same file name apppage1.js

Comment: If I remove this text:resultrows.fieldByName('destination') and instead if I give text:'hi'..this tableview is displaying

Comment: check value of `resultrows.fieldByName('destination')` using `Ti.API.info` , maybe some would be null ( so it would give an error )

Comment: The errors got cleared by cut paste the label,fieldnames nad button inside the while loop..thanks all for the comments..I hv a doubt to ask can I post it as different question or update it in this question

Comment: better would be to post a new question ( it will be visible to other users too ).

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that you aren't assigning anything to resultrows.

There is no query against the database, something like

```
var resultrows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM newtrip');
while (resultrows.isValidRow()) { ...
```

I'm not sure how you are getting into the while loop to display your text: 'hi' as you are saying.

The error doesn't seem to match what you should be seeing.  Wondering if too much code is removed to help with this example.

Comment: Sorry! I hv already assingned the values for resultrows,forgot to paste it here..its the same SELECT query

Comment: You'll need to give a more complete example.  You can't copy and paste code that you believe is important.  The code you aren't putting in might be the reason for the error.  Please update your code in your original post.